# Deleted part of /usr/bin

Tags: ubuntu, installation, python

I was navigating on my Ubuntu 12.10 64bit box through Windows WinSCP with *root* user and suddenly pressed "delete" "enter" when I was on *usr* directory. I immediately cancelled the delete process and the mess was already done. I got **no python3** interpreter:

```
-bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: invalid interpreter: File or directory not found.
```

Please, don't say reinstall your system or boot a LiveCD.
I can't use dpkg or apt-get to reinstall the packages.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I can't use dpkg or apt-get to reinstall the packages." That deserves some explanation, don't you think? If those have been destroyed by this action then the question changes to "How to rtestore dpkg and apt-get".

Comment: This type of question has been asked and answered several times, in several of the SE groups.  Have you not researched the archives to come to the proper conclusion which you want nobody to say?

Comment: I can't use dpkg or apt-get because them throw the same damn error.

Comment: I searched, and none helped. Seems my problem is a little different, because people without python working was still able to apt-get install --reinstall python3 and I can't. I even downloaded the deb's from packages.ubuntu.com but no avail.

Comment: You didn't delete python ONLY. You deleted a LOT of stuff. And you failed to keep backups. Sorry that you don't like the answer, but the answer is that you reinstall.

Answer (score 4):

You don't necessarily have to reinstall your system, IF you have good backups.....You can restore the missing directories from your fine backups!

Otherwise.....you'll have to re-(can't say according to the questioner)...

Comment: IF. I don't have any backups at all.

Comment: Re: Proper Backups. Which, in my less than humble opinion, is part of what separates professional IT from Hobbyist.